# How to print out the index of a boolean array?

Tags: java, arrays, boolean

I'm trying to get all of the indexes of a Boolean array to be printed out where its element is true. The end goal is to be able to find a prime number of the indexes (where I change each index number that isn't prime to false in the array) then print out only what is left of the prime numbers of the indexes of the array.

The very first step I'm just trying to do is at least to get *some integer index* to print out, but nothing seems to be working and I don't know what is wrong.

```
public class PriNum{
    private boolean[] array;

    public PriNum(int max){
        if (max > 2){ //I don't have any problems with this if statement
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        else{
            array = new boolean[max];

            for(int i = 0; i < max; i++){
                if(i == 0 || i == 1){ //Automatically makes 0 and 1 false 
                                      //because they are not prime
                    array[i] = false;
                }
                else{
                    array[i] = true;
                }
            }
            toString(); //I know for sure the code gets to here 
                        //because it prints out a string I have
                        // there, but not the index
        }
    }

    public String toString(){
        String s = "test"; //this only prints test so I can see if 
                           //the code gets here, otherwise it would just be ""

        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if(array[i] == true){
                s = s + i; //Initially I tried to have the indexes returned
                         //to be printed and separated by a comma,
                         //but nothing comes out at all, save for "test"
             }
         }

        return s;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Included is the driver class that's requesting the print of the class PriNum

```
class Driver{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        PriNum theprime = null;

        try{
            theprime = new PriNum(50);
        }
        catch (IllegalArgumentException oops){
            System.out.println("Max must be at least 2.");
        }

        System.out.println(theprime);
    }
}
```

Comment: `private boolean[] array;` is never intialized.  What is `numbers` ?  I think this code would not even compile.

Comment: What is `max`, and what index do you expect to be true. I note you have a typo (missing `}` before your `else` in that first loop). Also, how are you printing this? Calling `toString()` and doing nothing with the result doesn't accomplish much.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch `max` is supposed to be the maximum size of the array, and it is being printed by a driver class outside of this class (which I can also include if that's necessary), and thanks for catching the typo; it's fixed now

Comment: @ScaryWombat whoops, the numbers was an error on my part, it was supposed to be `array` for me to tell what exactly I'm working with.

Comment: Er, you don't have a print statement?  You also dont have anything calling this method - might you be calling it with 0 or 1?  Sounds like you're trying to make  sieve of erasthones (or at least, what you're doing can be used for one).

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse I'm not quite sure what you mean by that, however if it can be used to find prime numbers, then I'll definitely take a look into that. Regarding the print statement, I just finished editing the code and included another class that's got the print statement!

Comment: after reading your code, I guess you want `if (max < 2) throw...` not `if (max > 2) throw...` , don't you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numbers is initialized without declaration, array is declared but not initialized anywhere in your code. You have also a syntax error after array[i] = true, should be curly brace...

Comment: That was an error on my part; `numbers` was supposed to be `array`. It's fixed now along with the syntax error!

Comment: I think your code would always throw the IllegalArgumentException cos argument is always more than 2 (50), means toString() doesn't get called at all or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I tried running this, and the first change that needs to happen is to set this argument:

```
if(max < 2)
```

Then, if I'm reading this correctly: 0 and 1 are false. Every index after that is true. The output is fine as I see it. Just all the numbers crunched as a continuous list.

To get a better output, put a space between indexes:

```
if(array[i] == true){
    s = s + " " + i;
}
```

You may even just output to screen directly as

```
if(array[i])
 System.out.print( i );
```